# Creating a list of list from a text input

Tags: python

I am attempting to create a list that contains lists that is read in from a .txt file. Preferably the inner list well be integers

I have created two variables created from the text file sink which is the first and raw which is a slice of the orginal text file from [1:]

example input from txt file

4,0,5,3,0,0,0,2,4,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0

sink = 4

raw = ['0', '5', '3', '0', '0', '0', '2', '4', '0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0']

The first number represents the division (4) and well change as the lists get larger or smaller.
So I would want to create something like this
g = [[0,5,3,0],[0,0,2,4],[0,0,0,5],[0,0,0,0]]

Apologies I deleted my attempts.

```
class Reader:
    #place holder for rawData
   rawData = []
   file = open("test4.txt")
   rawData = file.read()
   file.close()     
   rawData = rawData.split(',')

r = Reader()
sink = int(r.rawData[0])
source = 0 #(this is for calculations in other parts of the program)
raw = r.rawData[1:]
```

Comment: Hello! Can you add the code you wrote to read from the file and obtain the result? Also if you have tried anything to achieve what you want and the errors you get in case.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the length of raw will always be divisible by sink this will get you what you need!

```
sink = 4
raw = ['0', '5', '3', '0', '0', '0', '2', '4', '0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0']

g = [raw[i:i+sink] for i in range(0, len(raw), sink)]

print(g)
```

If you prefer it not in a comprehension then this would be the loop:

```
sink = 4
raw = ['0', '5', '3', '0', '0', '0', '2', '4', '0', '0', '0', '5', '0', '0', '0', '0']

g = []
for i in range(0, len(raw), sink):
    g.append(raw[i:i+sink])

print(g)
```